# how to create xml backgroup for liner layout?

Tags: android, xml

i wanna create xml backgroud for item of my list but backgroun must be like it

[image]

how to do it, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to create new xml for backgound, just add to the items xml this background

```
android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame"
```